# Android - Deleting item from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayList that has 6 values in it. When I click a button I have one of these values deleted then a new value is added to the ArrayList. Everything works perfectly but when I get to the last original item in the ArrayList and try to delete it, the app crashes. Here is an example,

My ArrayList contains these variables `"1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6"` When I push a button the first item of the ArrayList is removed, then another item is added. So, it would look like this, `"2", "3","4", "5", "6", "New Value"` I keep doing this until I get to the last original item in the ArrayList. It looks like this, `"6", "New Value","New Value", "New Value", "New Value", "New Value"` When I hit the button to delete the item `"6"` the app crashes.

Here is my ArrayList code,

```
String[] values = new String[] { "1", "2", "3",
                "4", "5", "6" };  
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          list.add(values[i]);
        }
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.main_activity_list_item, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the code I use to delete and add new ArrayList items,

```
Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    list.add("New Value");
                    list.remove(0);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

This is the StableArrayAdapter,

```
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }

      }
```

And this is the CatLog,

```
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.example.LoginActivity$StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(LoginActivity.java:183)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.widget.AdapterView.rememberSyncState(AdapterView.java:1169)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:798)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5630)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:35)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.example.LoginActivity$2.onTouch(LoginActivity.java:157)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5574)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1965)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1734)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1965)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1734)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1965)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1734)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1965)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1734)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1965)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1734)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1982)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1441)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2421)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1930)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5759)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2970)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2529)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:869)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2538)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-04 00:28:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(17775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why you are using OnTouchListener ?

Comment: The OnTouchListener was a button I already created for something else and I didn't want to create a new button so I just placed the code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ..

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }
```

You will make change like this..

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {       
      return position;
    }
```

get item id means it will return a position That's all you will Use the custom adapter like this It will useful to you....

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public ArrayList<String> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);       
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());      
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You also need to override `getItem` in `StableArrayAdapter` Adapter as:

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}
```

because by default `getItem` method return `null`

**EDIT :**

To add elements in Map is pre-increment of `i` instead of Post as:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
  }
```

Comment: but why OP getting NPE at 6th attempt? why not first? OP saying that `I am getting NPE when trying to remove 6`...

Comment: @GopalRao : my answer is accoding to what logcat saying instead of OP saying

Comment: Isn't my `getItem` in `StableArrayAdapter` already have `@Override`? Sorry I'm just not completely understanding what I need to change my code to.